# Handling Feature Detection When Javascript Is Turned Off

Tags: javascript, css, modernizr, feature-detection

Feature detection is very important for making sure your website is compatible with all browsers. I think that if we are accounting for older browsers and user agents with fewer features it is very important we also account for those with javascript turned off. Here's my issue (In all the following examples I am using modernizr):

Lets say we have a piece of css to detect when gradients are available:

```
.cssgradients .div-that-needs-gradient {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, yellow);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(red, yellow);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, yellow);
    background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}

.no-cssgradients .div-that-needs-gradient {
    background-image: url('http://example.com/gradient-image.png');
}
```

How this code works is a library like modernizr detects when gradients are available than places either the `cssgradients` or the `no-cssgradients` class on the html element. What happens if javascript is turned off? Now neither of these css rule sets activate. The user is now stuck with a ugly blank background. What would you guys say is the best way to approach this?

Thanks for any help!

### Solution

```
.no-js .div-that-needs-gradient {
    background: orange
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, yellow);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(red, yellow);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, yellow);
    background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}

.cssgradients .div-that-needs-gradient {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, yellow);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(red, yellow);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, yellow);
    background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}

.no-cssgradients .div-that-needs-gradient {
    background-image: url('http://example.com/gradient-image.png');
}
```

Comment: use a default that looks at least ok in any browser

Comment: I don't think you need all these vendor prefixes anymore See [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=grad).

Comment: @torazaburo Click on the "show all" button. Some of the prefixes might be in really old browsers, but I don't see how to could hurt to provide a slightly better experience in some older browsers.

Comment: Because it's not needed. All webapp development assumes that user's browsers are updated to within three or four versions of most recent. It's more complexity, more code, and poorer performance.

Comment: I wonder what percentage of browsers have JS turned off for sites that they actually intend to use?  And, then of those, what percentage of those are actually interesting customers that you could ever make any money off?  I personally think the cost of supporting customers that have JS turned off is way, way higher than those small number of customers are worth.  Same with old versions of IE.  I'd much rather use those dev resources to advance the experience for the 99% rather than support the 1%.  It's a pure tradeoff.

Comment: @torazaburo I dont think you can possibly assume that, but god knows why a lot of people don't update there browsers. The only prefix there that you can definitely sacrifice is the -o- prefix cause according to caniuse.com only 0.01% of people use the browser that requires it. According to caniuse.com, 8.75% of people require a prefix to see a gradient in their browser, and 8.56% of people don't support gradients at all.

Comment: @jfriend00 Your not sacrificing anything if you do progressive enhancement.

Comment: You're completely ignoring the opportunity cost of doing special development and testing for very small numbers of users and forcing your architecture a certain way.  That development time could be better spent (in my opinion) developing features for the 99%.  Remember, this is pretty much a zero sum game where any time/resource spent supporting a user that has no JS is time taken away from other features for everyone else.  Plus even having a functional site without JS rules out 90% of the architectures one might find the most advantageous.

Comment: Progressive enhancement for no JS users locks you into a specific type of architecture and costs you a lot of development time and testing.  I'd hate to be a site designer when all major features had to work without JS.  It's going to seriously compromise the design for the 99%.  Not an appropriate business tradeoff in my book. You're welcome to have a different opinion if you want, but you have to understand what it's really costing you to make a fully functional version of your site without any JS and then try to make an awesome site for those who do have JS on top of that. Not easy or fast.

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't think I can speak for everybody, but I would say most would agree its very important to either use progressive enhancement or graceful degradation in your webapp.

Comment: @Dastur *I dont think you can possibly assume that*. It's not me assuming that. It's hundreds and thousands of companies that explicitly build that assumption into their browser support matrices. The idea that I need to support Chrome 3.0 is, frankly, ridiculous.

Comment: When I'm designing a site, I very carefully decide which users/browsers it is worth it to me to support.  And, for what I do, it's more important that I can deliver a great experience to 95+% of the population than delivering an OK experience to that last 5%.  It's a pure business decision.  It costs an enormous amount to support that last 5% and, guess what, many of those are the least interesting users from a business point of view too (super old browsers don't buy much).  Maybe if I'm Well Fargo bank, I have to work for everyone.  But, not if I'm the hottest new social networking app.

Comment: @jfriend00 First off, supporting chrome 3.0 is nearly pointless, no one uses that browser. Secondly, progressive enhancement does not sacrifice the experience of newer user agents, it expands on the experience of the older user agents. All of the older user agents get the not very cool experience, but the newer ones get the better more fun experience. The point is, that they both get a functional experience. Now one wants to use a broken website, and that is what progressive enhancement addresses. The only thing is that progressive enhancement does increase development time.

Comment: So, for a lot of what happens on the web, supporting the laggards is just a drag on resources that turns out to be a lousy business decision when those resources could be much better spent advancing the experience for the other 95%.  You make it sound like progressive enhancement for every single feature is simple.  It's not.  It's quite costly and forces you to make significant design tradeoffs too.  Well, we can't do X because we have no way to make that work for people without JS.  Or we have to do Y because of the no JS people.  Those are serious design compromises all over your site.

Comment: @jfriend00 You can't give a great experience to 95% of people without progressive enhancement. You'd be surprised how many people use older browsers.

Comment: Chrome 3.0 was not something I said.  You don't understand the cost of designing, implementing and testing progressive enhancement.  It's way cheaper to design ONE way for your app to work that works for the 95% than it is to design two ways that it works with progressive enhancement.  You also don't seem to understand how architecturally constraining supporting no JS is.

Comment: @jfriend00 Okay look, I don't really want to have an argument in the comments. I understand what you are saying, and you are entirely entitled to your opinion. I personally think that progressive enhancement is very important, and I think we should leave it at that, cause the comments expand really far now.

Comment: Well, it depends upon what you mean by older browsers.  But, I thought we were mostly talking about Javascript or no Javascript.  I frankly don't care to support people who have turned Javascript off.  If you want to use my site, turn it on.  If not, too bad - I'll make a much greater experience for the rest.

Comment: @jfriend00, i sort of agree with that, i think your site should be designed for users with javascript, but you should attempt to make it possible for users with javascript turned off to use the website, and also add the classic 'Looks like you have javascript turned off' notification. I was more talking about older browsers. Also the reason i mentioned the chrome 3.0 thing is because i thought it was you when torazaburo said something up there.

Comment: I'm sorry, what? Javascript disabled? Last time someone measured it, it was about 1% (and probably overestimated). Don't waste your time. Javascript is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your particular case:

```
.div-that-needs-gradient {
    background-image: url('http://example.com/gradient-image.png');
    background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}
```

Modern browsers that understand both will first apply the `url`, then override it with the `linear-gradient` . Older browsers will just apply the `url` and ignore the `linear-gradient`. Remember that, in CSS, the last declaration in a rule-set has priority over those that came before.

But, also consider this:

> Instead of building a great experience as the default and then hoping
>   it degrades to something that is still usable in less capable
>   browsers, you build a basic experience that works in all browsers, and
>   then layer an enhanced experience on top of that.

From [here](https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Optimizing_content_for_different_browsers:_the_RIGHT_way#Browser_detection_is_not_the_way_to_go.21).

Or, [as suggested by Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/), you could target specific browsers instead of features:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

And then, remove the "no-js" from `<html>` using javascript.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but this is an issue because the image will load than get overriden, so you are adding extra load time on an image that is just being overriden.

Comment: @Dastur A horizontally repeated linear gradient image with a 90 degree angle and 1px width usually weigths around 1 kB. Modernizr weights 45  kB. Maybe you should priorize tools that give you more bang for your buck.

Comment: Thanks, the last one is definitely what I'm looking for, If you check out the comment above, I was definitely already considering progressive enhancement .